# "cannot find symbol" in Java (two different classes in the same package)

Tags: java

I've created two classes called "Rettangolo" and "TestRettangolo". The first one define terms of the class like coordinates (for each angle) , height and width. Two methods. "Trasla" , to "moove" the rectangle and "toString" that returns a string with the coordinate of the top-left-angle and down-right-angle.

The second one its made just for "introduce me" the way how classes works togheter in the same package. It has only a void main.
Inside it I create a Rettangolo obj and than I call the other two methods. Nothing else.

I've search only for two hours straight. All variables , classes and methods are public and apparently correct. There are no errors.
(I'm using Eclipse on Linux Mint. I use CLI to compile and run java files.)

"Rettangolo Class"

```
package lab_2;

public class Rettangolo
{
    public double x , y , lunghezza , altezza;
    
    public Rettangolo(double x, double y, double lunghezza, double altezza)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.lunghezza = lunghezza;
        this.altezza = altezza;
    }
    
    public void trasla(double a, double b)
    {
        x += a;
        y += b;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "("+x+" , "+y+") --> ("+x+lunghezza+" , "+y+altezza+")";
    }
}
```

"TestRettangolo class"

```
package lab_2;

public class TestRettangolo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rettangolo forma = new Rettangolo(0,0,20,10);
        
        System.out.println("Rettangolo pre-change\n");
        System.out.println(forma.toString()+"\n\n");
        
        forma.trasla(10, -5);
        
        System.out.println("Rettangolo post-change\n");
        System.out.println(forma.toString()+"\n\n");    
    }
}
```

Error that I've got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QNQW.png)

Comment: and ... what is the actual error you get?

Comment: TestRettangolo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  Rettangolo forma = new Rettangolo(0,0,20,10);
  ^
  symbol:   class Rettangolo
  location: class TestRettangolo
TestRettangolo.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  Rettangolo forma = new Rettangolo(0,0,20,10);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Rettangolo
  location: class TestRettangolo
2 errors


(((The text in comment section seems to be not allineated so I've edit the post , you can check the screenshot)))

Comment: @Reimeus Now It "worked". But when I type  "java TestRettangolo.java" it gives me the same error. Still dont know why

Comment: did you actually compile that Rettangolo class?

Comment: Yes I did. No problems here fortunately

Comment: Actually i've discovered something strange. Linux Mint compiler only gives me this error. Btw if I try to compile it on Eclipse it works without any problems. Never seen this before

Comment: in short: **1)** both classes must be in a folder called `lab_2` (the package name); **2)** the parent folder of `lab_2` must be on the CLASSPATH

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Next time I will do it <3